# Erfahren über/von

Tags: preposition

Ich lerne nur seit einem Jahr Deutsch und ich möchte gern wissen, welche Präposition man mit "erfahren" verwenden soll? 
Ein Beispiel: Schreibt man "Im Film erfahre ich über sein Leben" oder "Im Film erfahre ich von seinem Leben". 
Ich habe im Internet gesucht und ich habe sowohl *über* als auch *von* gefunden, und ich möchte deswegen gern wissen, ob es einen Unterschied gibt.

Comment: *erfahren über* hast du hoffentlich nicht gefunden.

Comment: @tofro: Warum hoffst du das? Zum Beispiel: *»Im Film erfahre ich über sein Leben, dass er in Indien geboren wurde, zu Fuß nach Peking marschiert ist, und dann ein Lehrer der Kaisers wurde.«*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast meinem Sprachgebrauch nach kann man "etwas über etwas" erfahren. Ich würde deinen Beispielsatz als ungewöhnlich, wenn nicht falsch, betrachten.

Comment: @tofro: _»Gestern habe ich viel über ihn erfahren.«_

Comment: @Pollitzer: Viel ist ja auch etwas. Aber ich stimme auch Hubert darin zu, dass sich *etwas* durch einen dass-Satzteil ersetzen lässt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ja, Recht hat immer der Mapper. Meine Aussage bezieht sich auf tofros ersten Kommentar, seinen zweiten habe ich wohl übersehen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Kurt hat gestern von Annas Unfall erfahren.

This means, that Kurt didn't know before, that Anna had an accident. Yesterday someone told it to Kurt, so he got noticed about Anna's accident yesterday.

But this doesn't mean, that Kurt now knows many details about her accident. It is possible, that he has been told some details too, but this information is not in this sentence. The sentence just says: Yesterday Kurt got the information, that Anna had an accident.

> Kurt hat gestern etwas über Annas Unfall erfahren.

This sentence says, that yesterday Kurt got some information about Annas accident. This sentence doesn't tell you, if Kurt knew about her accident before, but you can suppose it. It is very likely, that Kurt knew before, that she had an accident. But you know for sure, that yesterday someone told him some details about the accident that he din't know before.

> Kurt hat gestern etwas über Anna erfahren.

Now the topic is not an accident, it is Anna. Yesterday Kurt got some information about her. It is very obvious that Kurt did know Anna before, but yesterday he learned something about her, that he didn't know before.

> Kurt hat gestern etwas von Anna erfahren.

This sentence is ambiguous. This sentence can mean the same as the sentence above. But there is an alternative interpretation, which is this:
This sentence doesn't tell us what it was that was told to Kurt. But we know, that it was Anna who told it to him. She transported the information and gave it to Kurt, what ever this information was.

> <del>Kurt hat gestern über Annas Unfall erfahren.</del>
> <del>Kurt hat gestern über Anna erfahren.</del>

This is wrong. If you use »über« you need »etwas« too. Instead of the word »etwas« you also can use a more explicit description of the information, for example:

> Kurt hat gestern über Anna erfahren, dass sie die Tochter von Walter ist.

Notice, that in this case *von* can also be used instead of *über*:

> Kurt hat gestern von Anna erfahren, dass sie die Tochter von Walter ist.

So, this sentence can be interpreted in two different ways:

1. It was Anna, who told something about herself to Kurt.
2. It was someone else who talked about Anna.

In this case you need some more information from the context, to find out which meaning is correct.

Comment: +1, but you should emphasize the *If you use »über« you need »etwas« too.* rule. *A über B wissen/erfahren* is the rare case where a preposition commands a preceding object.

Comment: @Janka: Die Regel, dass *über* ein *etwas* erfordert, ist auch nicht ganz einfach, wie man an diesem Beispiel sieht: *Gestern  habe ich über Anna erfahren, dass Kurt wegzieht.*

Comment: Guys, is it correct to think of "erfahren von" = "learn OF" (I've just now learned OF this), and "erfahren über"  = "learn about" (I learned about this at school)? If so, I think this is a much easier way to explain the difference, especially to native Englishers?

Comment: @BuzzKirill: 1. The answer should be helpful for everyone, even for those for whom English is also a foreign language. (Many refugees from Ukraine or Islamic countries already know some English and want to learn German.) 2. How does your suggestion help to understand the ambiguity of *»Kurt hat gestern etwas von Anna erfahren«?* 3. *»to learn of something«* can also mean *»aus etwas lernen«* which has a very different meaning than *»etwas erfahren«* (*We can learn of other experience = Wir können aus anderen Erfahrungen lernen* It's not Wir können von anderen Erfahrungen erfahren)

Comment: "This sentence is ambiguous." Actually, "Kurt hat gestern etwas über Anna erfahren." is just as ambiguous, as "über" can mean "via" - that is, the information was passed on from person to person, until it ended up with Anna, who then told Kurt.

Answer (score 0):

**Kurze Antwort**: Wenn schon, dann „erfahren **von** *etwas*“.

**Lange Antwort**: *Erfahren* ist ein starkes Verb: Was man erfährt, steht im näheren Objekt. Eine Präposition ist hier fehl am Platz.
Das Objekt ist aber oft generisch und wird erst durch eine Präpositionalgruppe genauer beschrieben. Man erfährt z.B.

- etwas *über* die Grammatik
- ein Detail *aus* seinem Leben
- neues *von* der Wahl
- mehr *zum* Thema

Gelegentlich trifft man auf Sätze, in denen das (nichtssagende) Objekt oder Adverbial einfach weggelassen wird. Das halte ich für falsch (oder zumindest für schlechten Stil).

**Sonderfall „erfahren von *etwas*“**:

- Ich erfahre ∅ von ihrer Krankheit = Ich erfahre, **dass** sie krank ist.
- Er erfährt ∅ von der Wahl = Er erfährt, **dass** eine Wahl stattfand / geplant ist.

Ich finde hier kein Objekt oder Adverbial, das anstelle von ∅ eingesetzt werden könnte, ohne den Sinn der Sätze zu verändern. Deshalb vermute ich hier tatsächlich ein präpositionales Objekt — auch wenn das so nicht im Duden steht.

Das gilt jedoch nur für die Präposition *von*. Bei allen anderen Präpositionen klingt der Satz schon wesentlich besser, wenn man zum Beispiel *etwas* als näheres Objekt davor setzt.